# Merging of 2 regions creates a fade-in at the beginning in Logic Pro

Tags: logic-pro, looping

I'm trying to create a perfect loop of car engine in Logic Pro:

1. I've got a car engine sample of constant pitch
2. Split in at the middle
3. Then swapped the parts and crossfaded:

[image]

But, when I try to join/merge these parts, Logic Pro adds tiny fade in at the beginning, which spoils the work done:

[image]

How to avoid that? 'Cause the loop becomes basically useless!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to resolve the issue when merging the regions but you could try to Bounce In Place instead.  Very quick and easy to do and it shouldn't cause a fade in like that.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, and it gives exactly the same result. Could you please check it on your side? I'm getting suspicious...

Comment: I just tried it out and didn't have any fade in or anything.  I did a bounce in place to test.

Comment: You can check the Region section of the Inspector window to see if there is fade in added there.  If you have that section open and don't see it, you need to click the More dropdown.  If there is any value next to fade in, then it is applying a fade in; if it's blank, that's not your issue.  There would usually be a little white area showing the fade in, very similar to the crossfade,  so I'm doubting this is it but worth checking.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it tomorrow. Really strange